# How to write EF Core query that translates to T-SQL Contains

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, entity-framework-core, full-text-search

I have set up a full text index and the following T-SQL statement works for me in SSMS:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Person 
WHERE CONTAINS(FirstName, '"joh*"')
```

But I cannot figure out how to write the equivalent query in EF Core

```
query.Where(p => EF.Functions.Contains(p.FirstName, $"'\"joh*\"'"));
```

I get an error from that code.

Can anyone help - how to do this in EF Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems every time I post a question, I was able to figure it out 5 mins later

this is what worked for me

```
query = query.Where(p => EF.Functions.Contains(p.FirstName, $"\"jo*\""));
```